# How to convert decimal? to decimal while using LINQ with a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

```
public static decimal getall(ref decimal? number)
{
    var sigma = from p in db.getDPMO1(ref number)
                select p.Sigma;
    return sigma; // I am getting Cannot Convert decimal? to decimal
}
```

Here is my stored procedure that takes a decimal parameter

```
ALTER PROCEDURE getDPMO1
    (@number Decimal OUTPUT)
AS
    SELECT
        MIN(Sigma_Value) AS Sigma 
    FROM
        Sigma_Table 
    WHERE
        Defect_Rate < @number

    RETURN
```

Comment: you can try with "return sigma.Value" in you c# code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that there are no rows which satisfy your condition `Defect_Rate < @number` thus the result would be `null`, not `0`.

You can change your sql to be `COALESCE(MIN(Sigma_Value), 0)` or `ISNULL(MIN(Sigma_Value), 0)` if you need a solid number. Also note that your return type for your stored procedure should be defined as `NOT NULL`.

Or, you can change your code to expect nulls. That is, change your return type to `decimal?` rather than `decimal`.

Comment: decimal dpmp1 = notMet / met + notMet * 100;
 decimal ans2 = Summary_Matrics_Client.getall(dpmp1); I am getting error "Invalid arguments" while calling ,please help

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
 public static decimal getall(ref decimal? number)
 {
    var sigma = from p in db.getDPMO(ref number)
                select p.Sigma;
    return sigma ?? 0; //for null sigma return 0       
 }
```